# How do i put area and country code

Tags: mysql, sql, sybase

So i created a table where i have to put only the numbers from 1000000 and 9999999. Plus the country code (57) and if starts with certain number the code area will be either 1,2,3,4,5,6,7 or 8.

```
create table MEDICOSUN(
phone bigint not null, 
constraint validPhone check(phone between 1000000 and 9999999))
```

Do i have to create another table with the country code, area code, and name of the area code? Thank you.

Comment: The number cannot start with `112` How do you check this?

Comment: save yourself many tears: use varchar for phone numbers.

Comment: Sybase or MySQL? Two different products, with somewhat different versions of SQL.

Comment: @cha, depends on the country...

Comment: 57 is the country code of Colombia

Answer (score 0):

That completely depends on how you want the database designed. First off, I don't know why you are putting a phone number in a bitint, but you don't *have* to put the country code, area code, etc... in another table. You can add them to the same table; however, as I said, it depends on how you want the database designed.

If you're trying to set them up so the area code and name of the area code are PK values then you can place them in another table and create a FK in your MEDICOSUN table that points to those.

If you need more help, you're going to have to be a little more specific with what you are trying to do.